# how to create a portfolio when you have never got hired?

Tags: freelance-websites, web-development, portfolio

I am training on converting PSD files To HTML , I get the PSDs from upwork ,
is it right to upload the done work in free domain and put it in my portfolio ?

Answer (score 3):

Offer your services to non-profits, charities, schools, or struggling businesses. Instead of asking for monetary payment, ask for publicly-available review postings and recommendations.

If you donate your services to reliable and reputable organizations, it can help prove your credibility while giving you a real-world challenge outside your comfort zone.

Answer (score 1):

Create a portfolio based on your skills.
I make websites, graphics, and animations.

If I was to make a portfolio, I would start off with making websites I believe are trending or short animated films.

Lastly, publish them on platforms like Behance, or Youtube. This way you may just get noticed or garner a following.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a portfolio is to show off your skills (and creativity in some cases). You can do this without any *actual* work. When people graduate from schools they start with "student work" in their portfolio. It's understood by those hiring that "student work" is not necessarily real-world work but is merely to show what the person may be capable of.

Start by looking at the areas in which you want to be hired. What skills are beneficial to those seeking that work? How can you show those skills in a portfolio?

Then create your own projects to show your skills. If you specialize in front-end mark up, then create a front-end web page for some fictitious company. If you specialize in CSS then create a page which shows off your CSS skills well. If you focus on front end conversion but have *no* design skills, then you're in a tough spot. It's hard to show off front-ed skills if you aren't a designer. You may want to merely find some small web sites which are very poorly constructed, then rebuild those sites to a more modern, fluid, responsive markup.

To be honest, I don't know how prevalent PSD2HTML is any longer. It was big 10-15 years ago but I've had almost no call for that workflow in quite a while. However, that just may be my experience (I do not use crowdsourcing sites like upwork).

If you are wanting to show off your PSD to HTML skills, then you need to be clear that you are *not* the designer and merely a "translator" in a sense. You'll need to show an image of the original PSD then your interpretation of that design.

In most instances, unless otherwise stated, showing work you've done in a portfolio is fine. But be certain to check any contracts or terms with your clients first. Some contracts restrict displaying content or may have a Non-Disclosure Agreement attached. In which case, you clearly shouldn't be showing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Make some demo's of what you would do.. if you're going to be offering the service of converting PSD's to HTML, it's safe to say that you have or have had access to (and can get) PSD files right? So why not make some Screenshots of:

Slide 1) A PSD File
Slide 2) Said PSD FIle after it has been converted to HTML (in raw code)
Slide 3) the finished HTML result in either your WYSIWYG editor or browser

Do that for 2-3 files (at 3 slides per file conversion, that would be 6-8 quality shots) - and sign up for an online "portfolio builder" site (go for a freebie in this case) for that https://www.crevado.com is great or I also like https://www.pagexl.com

That should be more than sufficient for you to create a stunning visual for literally nothing, and it shouldn't take you more than a total of 30 minutes MAX

Hope that helps